# Obtaining a value from a request function and passing it into another request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have a request function to which I pass url1 and obtain a value called latitude and then use it to make a new url and pass it into another request function. So how do I use the value obtained in one request function outside of that request function

```
var url1 = {some url}
var latitude;
request(url1, function (error1, response1, body1) {
    if (error1){
        return console.log('Error:', error1);
    }

    if (response1.statusCode !== 200) {
        return console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response1.statusCode);
    }

    var obj1 = JSON.parse(body1);
    latitude = obj1.response.data[0].latitude;
});

// I want to use this latitude that to make a new url and use it another request function          
var url2 = {some url + latitiude}
request(url2, function (error2, response2, body2) {
    if (error2) {
        return console.log('Error:', error2);
    }

    if (response2.statusCode !== 200) {
        return console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response2.statusCode);
    }
});
```

So how do I pass the latitude value from the first request function to the new url2? When I tried the latitude variable was not accesible outside the first request function.

Comment: callbacks or promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callbacks to pass the values obtained from first function to second function,

```
var url1= {some url}        
var latitude;   
request(url1, function (error1, response1, body1) {    
     //some code
     var obj1= JSON.parse(body1);    
     latitude = obj1.response.data[0].latitude;     

     var url2 = {some url + latitiude}    
     request(url2, function (error2, response2, body2) {    
        //some code          
     });  
});
```

Comment: For now I have done the same thing but what if I want to separate the 2 request functions and not use them one inside the other ?

Comment: your code is `async`. By the time, you tries to access `url2`, it is `undefined`. Unless, you wait for the response from request1, you can't get valid values.